# How to read from html files in electron production builds?

Tags: electron

When I run Electron mode in dev mode, it can read from HTML files fine. But when I build it into an exe, I get this error.

```txt
Error: ENOENT, src\renderer\login_success.html not found in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\edbdatalab\resources\app.asar
```

How can I include the files in the final build?

Comment: Can you please add your code to your question where you reference your `.html` file in the `win.loadFile()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Local file(s) (paths) displayed in an Electron window should be created within the main process and not by the render process.

Additionally, use of Node's `path` module and `__dirname` will greatly assist in building a correct absolute path, no matter where the application is run, be it in development or production, or on what operating system.

> Note the use of `nodePath.join(__dirname, 'path\to\file.html')` in the code below.

`main.js` (main process)

```js
// Import required electron modules
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

// Import required Node modules
const nodePath = require('path');

// Prevent garbage collection
let loginSuccessWindow;

function createLoginSuccessWindow() {
    const loginSuccessWindow = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            sandbox: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    loginSuccessWindow.loadFile(nodePath.join(__dirname, 'renderer\login_success.html'))
        .then(() => { loginSuccessWindow.show(); });

    return loginSuccessWindow;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    loginSuccessWindow = createLoginSuccessWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createLoginSuccessWindow();
    }
});
```